# Automatic Download of Youtube Channels

Tags: youtube

I have a couple of Youtube channels I subscribe to. I'm subscribed both on Google Reader and on Youtube itself. **Is there an app that checks for new updates to my subscribed channels and downloads them automatically (perhaps once a day)?**

My objective is to always have a few videos I can watch while on the road (and offline). I love how Google Listen syncs really well with my Google Reader podcasts and downloads them automatically, but it doesn't work with video podcasts. So is there an app that will do the same with my video podcasts? (either with Google Reader or with Youtube)

*Running 2.1-eclair if it matters.*

Comment: BeyondPod Podcast Manager should do that. There is a "Lite" version with 7 day trial: https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.beyondpod

Answer (score 2):

YouTube itself doesn't provide any way to download videos for offline viewing; any application that would let you do this would have to scrape the page to download the FLV (Flash Video) file, and then let you play the file on the phone; this might violate the Terms of Service for YouTube.

Basically, there probably isn't a way to do this, at least no legitimate way.